# How force download .gpx files in an Apache with an Apache Handler?

Tags: apache2

Actually I am in an Apache Server.
In some html pages we are linking some .GPX files so our users can download them.
Actually the GPX files are shown in the browser as XMLS files.

We need that our visitors download these files.
How force download .gpx files in an Apache with an Apache Handler?

Actually our hosting permit us to add the extension with an Apache Handler. Which one we need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using addhandler:

```
AddHandler application/octet-stream .gpx
```

or mod_rewrite (either in the VirtualHost or in .htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*\.gpx$ - [L,T=applicaton/octet-stream]
```

Comment: I have added it as you [can see here](http://respuestaslaborales.com/borrar/ApacheHandler.png) but the GPXs continue showing in the browser. Do it takes some time?

Comment: Try adding only `octet-stream`.

It is hard to know exactly what is going on as I do not know the control panel you are using. If the server has mod_rewrite enabled, you could try the snippet i included in a .htaccess file to see if that works. (You might need to remove `L,` depending on your setup.

Comment: Perfect.. Adding the code to the end of the .htaccess make it works!
Thanks a lot ot!